# Alembic API how to get raw SQL script

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

My requirement is to generate a SQL script and upload that script to cloud storage. I'm using Alembic Command to generate SQL script.

```
command.upgrade(alembic_cfg, revision='a:b', sql=True)
```

The `command.upgrade` function prints the SQL script into the console. If multiple revisions are there then there will be multiple `INFO` logs.

Is there any way to store the raw SQL script to a variable?

```
raw_sql = command.upgrade(alembic_cfg, revision='a:b', sql=True)
upload_script(raw_sql)
```

I know can make use of the cli `alembic upgrade head --sql > migration.sql`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like API is not available to achieve this. Finally, I have settled with the CLI command.

```
upgrade = subprocess.run(['alembic', 'upgrade', upgrade_revision_range, '--sql'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
raw_sql = upgrade.stdout.decode('utf-8')
```